# CRUD encrypted MYSQL

Tags: c++, mysql, c, encryption

[image]How to perform CRUD with MySQL when I wanted to store:

1. All columns of a row as encrypted
2. Only a specific column as encrypted.

Do I have to use blob as datatype for the columns while creating the table? or it works with varchar, int, and other datatypes. Where should I specify encryption key, I am thinking of keeping it as a hardcoded value in the program.

I am using C MYSQL connector(can change to C++ connector). A sample is much appreciated. At present my schema looks like this, please ignore row_hash column.

Comment: What's the point of encrypting data on mysql field level? None of the above fields warrant such treatment.

Comment: The requirements is to store the membership table or uid in membership table encrypted.

Comment: Then your requirements are probably wrong. The uid field is a key in several fields. If you encrypt it in the membership table then either you cannot maintain referential integrity, or you need to encrypt the uid field in every single table. But in the latter case, the encryption is pointless since the encrypted value acts as a reference point. Moreover, uid column seems to be a generated id field, so its value is meaningless without the data within the user table. Again, what's the point of field level encryption? What do you try to protect the data from?

Comment: I want no one(db admin) to know which user is member of which group.

Comment: Yeah, but the DBA is allowed to sell your users' email addresses, right? The solution to this is not a field level encryption. First of all, a DBA can switch on query logging, which would capture your key to the encryption in plain text and can reverse the data using that. So, the whole idea is pointless. This falls into the area of privileged user access and data loss prevention. Both are lot more complex topics than what a simple symmetric encryption would be able to handle.

Comment: So you mean to say, I am helpless here.

Comment: Not helpless. You are using a wrong approach. You need to do some proper thinking, rather than jumping to conclusions. I would even challenge that if you do not know anything else about your customers than their email addresses, then protecting group memberships is quite of an overreaction.

Comment: Asking for a guideline, if you could.

Comment: Is there a way I could hide user's membership details.

Comment: Anyways, how the crud operation with mysql done when the fields are encrypted.